# Python - When trying to run the code nothing happens. I don't even get an error

Tags: python, python-idle

I am trying to create a small betting application with Python and when I try to run the program nothing happens what so ever. I am using IDLE.
This is my code:

```
def bet():
    #balance = 100
    x = 0
    with open("bal.txt", "r") as f:
        for l in f:
            bal = (sum([int(a) for a in l.split()]))
            while bal > 0:
                print ("Your balance is: " + str(balance) + " credits.")
                while x == 0:
                    print ("Enter the amount you would like to bet:")
                    bet = int(input())
                    if bet > bal:
                        x = 0
                    elif bet < 0:
                        x = 0
                    else:
                        x = 1
                print ("Pick a number between 1 and 20")
                num = int(input())

                convbal = bal - bet
                print ("Your bet is now locked in...")
                print (" ")
                print (" ")

                import random
                rannum = random.randint(1, 20)
                print ("Your guess was: " + str(num))
                print (" ")
                print ("The random number was: " + str(rannum))

                if rannum == num:
                    print ("WINNER")
                    bal = bal + (bet * 2)
                else:
                    print ("LOSER")
                    print ("")
                    print ("")
```

This is the outcome I receive in shell:

[image: output]

Any idea will be great, thanks :)

Comment: Did you call bet()? If so, put in a few more calls to print to see which loops actually run.

Comment: Is this all your code? Its just a function which you don't call!

Comment: It depend on the content of `bal.txt`.

Comment: the function's not being called? But OP specifically shows the function being called in IDLE prompt in the [attached screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/z2gO7.png) as `>>> bet()`, no? It seems the question is not problem with the code logic, but rather the behavior that should be expected from IDLE.

Comment: It depend on the content of `bal.txt`, there would be an output just if `bal > 0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check bal.txt can be open and that it has at least one line whose sum is > 0. The thing here is that one of your conditions is failing

Comment: yeah thanks, I ended up having to move everything to a separate folder and try again as it created a new file instead of reading the one already in place? problem solved, just my stupidity

Answer (score 2):

The ONLY thing that code does is define a function named `bet`.  You could type `bet()` in the IDLE shell to call it, or put `bet()` at the bottom of the file (not indented!) to call it automatically.